# POST form with multiple submit elements

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Based on some quick examples found on SO and other sources, I am trying to use Python urllib/urllib2 to submit a form in the following manner:

```
>>> import urllib, urllib2
>>> url = 'http://example.com'
>>> r_params = {'a':'test','b':'hooray'}
>>> e_params = urllib.urlencode(r_params)
>>> user_agent = 'some browser and such'
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
>>> req = urllib2.Request(url, e_params, headers)
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> data = response.read()
```

I've gotten this to work, however, on the particular form I am looking for there are two buttons of type "submit". e.g.:

```
<b><input type="submit" name="ButtonA" value="SUBMIT"></b>
<b><input type="submit" name="ButtonB" value="LINK"></b>
```

I believe the problem I'm having results from the current code choosing the wrong one. How do I get a response by submitting ButtonB rather than ButtonA? Some of the stuff I've read seems to indicate that I could try using mechanize, but I was hoping to keep this simple without having to read up and learn mechanize. Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to suck it up and actually take the time to learn and understand what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fairly simple, if that's the case - you should look in to what exactly you're doing. Specifically, you're sending a POST request (urllib2.urlopen will send a POST request automatically if the data argument is supplied) with the data that would normally be supplied by the form element itself. In the case of multiple "submit" inputs, the name and value of the activated submit input is sent along with the rest of the form data.

So, that's all you have to do - include "ButtonB":"LINK" as data.

A quick reference so you can see how HTML does all the stuff it does:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format

Comment: I just made r_params = {'a':'test','b':'hooray','ButtonB':'LINK'}
and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a tool like [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) for Firefox to discover precisely how the site's POSTs are formed. Activate TamperData just before you're ready to click one of the buttons. When it's up, go ahead and click one. The POST will be recorded in TamperData. Find it and click on it.

Find the POSTDATA row below and double-click it. Select the "Decoded" radio button to remove the HTML escapes. Now you have a 1:1 reference you should copy when making your "r_params" dictionary. For instance, if the POSTDATA looked like this:

```
Name        | Value
--------------------
QueryString | test
Page        |
Search      | blah
```

then you will create your dictionary like this:

```
r_params = {'QueryString': 'test',
            'Page': '',
            'Search':, 'blah'}
```

After you've found out what the POSTDATA looks like for each separate submit event, you'll know how to create the right dictionary to send along. Also, be sure to confirm you are POSTing to the correct URL. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, thanks for this. I got this working and it makes much more sense what I'm doing now.